# Invoking Drupal core tests from within a custom module .test script

Tags: testing

I am writing a simpletest test script, where I would like to enable my module, and then invoke a Drupal core test to ensure that my module is producing core-compliant results (in particular, I render a pager alternative to core's, and would make sure that, at its minimal setup, is equal to core's one).

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for help

mondrake

Answer (score 2):

So... I found a solution that's working, at least for my case.

It has to do with the fact that test cases are actually PHP classes that can be extended. So I tried to leverage inheritance, with a caveat...

I want to run a test on the pager, Drupal 7, after I have enabled a module that replaces the core pager.

The core pager test class is defined as

```
class PagerFunctionalWebTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {
```

now, my problem was that the core test would not be caring about my module to be loaded before running the tests.

I created my module test class as an *extension* of the core one, like

```
class MyPagerTest extends PagerFunctionalWebTestCase {
```

This is OK, but the point is that if I call parent::setUp() at this stage, the core setup will be run and I will still miss my module from loading before the actual test.

So the caveat is that instead of calling parent::setUp, I will call directly the 'ancestor' DrupalWebtestCase::setUp function, with *my* setup, and skip the call to parent.

Like this:

```
...

public function setUp() {
  // Enable required modules.
  $modules = array(
    'dblog',
    'mypager',
  );
  DrupalWebTestCase::setUp($modules);

  // Insert 300 log messages.
  for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++) {
    watchdog('pager_test', $this->randomString(), NULL, WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
  }

  $this->admin_user = $this->drupalCreateUser(array(
    'access site reports',
  ));
  $this->drupalLogin($this->admin_user); 

}

....
```

That's all - class inheritance will do the magic and bring the rest of the test functions in.

Anybody sees other options?